# $X-Y$ equivalent in distribution to $0$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is equal to $Y$ in distribution, is it equivalent to $X-Y$ which is equivalent in distribution to $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: for example if $X$ is symmetric ($X$ has the same distribution as $-X$), then we can't say that $2X$ has the same distribution as $0$.

Comment: Thats true, i see

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot say anything about $X-Y$ if you only know the distribution of $X$ and $Y$. You need to know their joint distribution or some information based on which you can say something about the joint distribution for example independence. For instance if $Z=X-Y$ and the joint distribution of $X,Y$ is $ f_{XY}(x,y)$, then p.d.f of $Z$ is as follows:
$$
f_{Z}(Z)=\int f_{XY}(z+t,t)dt
$$
You can see that there is no need for the probability be concentrated at zero in general.